# Feat Selection for a Gestalt Druid/Ninja Wildshape assassin

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, optimization, feats

I know the title isn't terribly descriptive, hopefully someone can help me out on that one.

I'm stating out a Pathfinder Gestalt Druid/Ninja who is trying to maximize usage of Wild Shape paired with sneak attack. I know that Natural Spell ( cast spells while Wild Shaped ) and Wild Speech ( speak while Wild Shaped ) are useful, and those are on the list, but what other feats, including [Monster] feats, could the character take?

Short question: What Feats would make this build better?

Comment: "Does Improved Unarmed Strike carry over to natural attacks of the Wild Shape form?"  -- This implies a *lot* of confusion about natural attacks.  I'd suggest removing that question for now, and reading up on how they work.  (Then if you're still confused, make it a separate question.)

Comment: Phill, this question is unclear (what would be a good answer) and has sub questions.  Can you clarify it so that we know what a good answer would look like?

Comment: @C.Ross - is that any better? My apologies in advance.

Comment: I would recommend taking a one level dip of something with full BAB on the Ninja side at first level. Then the lost BAB from the classes with 3/4 BAB progression never synch up and you get full BAB. Which is good for the type of melee character you are playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick partial answer: a character may take Monster feats he qualifies for. Temporary qualification (as with Wild Shape) works, you just accept that your feat may not always help you. You cannot use a feat that you do not qualify for (barring bonus feats that say otherwise), so those feats may do nothing when you aren’t in Wild Shape.